# Negative predictions in polynomial regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to predict a value each week. I have 4 months and the actual value goes near to zero on weekends but never negative. My polynomial regression model is predicting well for weekdays and goes to way negative when actual is near to zero. How to correct this?

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print clf.predict(predict_)
```

Comment: That can happen when fitting polynomials especially with degrees > 1. You could try using other types of regression methods like Kalman filters or splines

Comment: I tried many methods, but this method is predicted well than others

Comment: Another possibility is first transforming the data to logarithmic scale (or log1p), then doing regression, and then transforming back. Then you do not get negative values

Comment: I am using onehot encoder to transform my features. Shall I use log only on y (Actual) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to only transform, 'NOT' fit, the test or predict dataset using the polynomial regression object that is used fit and transform the training data.

```
predict_ = poly.transform(predict)
```